# Kubernetes Dashboard behind AWS ELB or internal LB

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-dashboard

I have deployed K8s dashboard via 
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`.

And I can connect to the dashboard by running `kubectl proxy`.

My question is how can I expose this dashboard via internal LB or ELB?

I have changed the *kubernetes-dashboard service*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  # loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  # - x.x.x.x/32
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Then I hit the ELB DNS record and nothing return (eg - xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com).

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

note - This is a POC cluster and I don't have any issue with security concern at the moment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

And `https://<internal-lb-dns-record>` should work.